# How do I compare two text files excluding the first 5 characters of each line?

Tags: batch-file, compare, findstr

I'm trying to compare two files. They should be the same except for the firs 5 characters. I need the error file to contain the line(s) that do not match. Is there a way to limit the findstr command to only look at the characters at position 6 and beyond?

```
@echo off
echo Start %date% %time%
REM Verify that File1.txt and File2.txt are identical except for the first 5 characters
findstr /vio File1.txt File2.txt > Berror.txt
echo End %date% %time%
Berror.txt
Pause
```

File1.txt

```
00000spider
00000center
00000earwax
00000horn
00000cup
00000ton
00000ankle
00000foster
00000restaurant
00000ecstasy
```

File2.txt

```
46884spider
12464center
31197earwax
32514horn
64856cup
61465ton
91468anklet
31515foster
91580restaurant
41623ecstasy
```

I've tried using /r with [6-20] but I can't find an example with the sytax so I don't really know how to use it. The output I am expecting is line 7: 91468anklet and 00000ankle since that is the only line with a difference in this example.

Comment: `findstr`'s REGEX is heavily crippled. Anything not described in `for /?` just doesn't work. And `findstr` does always return the whole matching line (no way to extract some substring with `findstr`). You'll need temporary files with the first 5 characters of each line removed.

Comment: We can clearly see that there is a string difference on line seven of each file, but you need to show us **exactly** what you are expecting as a result. You also need to specify whether you are checking content in any line position of each file, or checking matching line numbers from each against each other.

Comment: @Compo - I am a newbie here. I don't know exactly what I am expecting. I just need to identify the rows that are different. The actual files are thousands of rows long. Each line should be exactly like its counterpart in the other file except for the first 5 characters. Line 1 character 12 in File1.txt should be exactly the same as line 1 character 12 in File2.txt.

Comment: If you don't know what you want to have as a result, it is not possible for us to show you how to get there. Please [Edit] your question to show us what exactly you want to see as output given your example content. Also we do need to know, for certain, if you are wanting to check line n of file 1 with the exact same line number in file 2, or if those lines can be in a different order in each file.

Comment: I want the output to say "Line 7" in a text file.

Comment: Can someone please point me in the direction of a good beginner resource for this topic. I apparently do not have enough technical expertise to ask a question on the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< file2.txt (
   for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" file1.txt') do (
      set "line1=%%b"
      set /P "line2="
      if "!line1:~5!" neq "!line2:~5!" (
         echo Line # %%a:
         echo File1: !line1!
         echo File2: !line2!
      )
   )
)
```

Output:

```
Line # 7:
File1: 00000ankle
File2: 91468anklet
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works! Unfortunately I don't understand it. Is there a resource you can recommend so that I can learn more?

Comment: @Nicole: take a look at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) for a complete list of commands and their syntax and options (not all of them work on all versions of Windows though), also don't miss the `How-To` button.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to split the .txt files before comparing. In this case it will be needed `cut -c 9-` to cut off the numbers in a line.
Ej:

```
echo "00121314JohnSmith" | cut -c 9-
JohnSmith
```

Comment: I was thinking about that. You mean to create two new txt files to compare?

Comment: `cut` is not available in `cmd`. You should mention what to install to make it work.